# How can I publish an npm package that already exists in AWS CodeArtifact to Github Packages using Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions, monorepo, github-package-registry, github-packages

I am working in a monorepo called `my_monorepo` that contains a project called `my_project` that I am trying to publish to Github Packages. The `my_monorepo/my_project/package.json` file currently looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "@my_monorepo/package_name",
  "version": "0.1.30",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/my_org/my_monorepo/my_project.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
  },
  ...
}
```

I have a package already published the package to AWS CodeArtifact and I want to publish it to Github Packages.

Within AWS CodeArtifact the package exists with a package name of `package_name` and namespace of `my_monorepo`. So it can be installed as `@my_monorepo/package_name`.

My workflow file looks like the below. I have temporarily set up the above to publish when I push changes, just while testing things out, but I intend on publishing on merge.

```
name: Publish Github Package

on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - "my_project/**"
    branches:
      - master

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./my_project
    shell: bash

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    name: Publish to Github Packages
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version-file: my_project/.nvmrc
          cache: "yarn"
          cache-dependency-path: "my_project/yarn.lock"
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - run: yarn build
      - run: yarn publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

However it fails to publish and throws the following error on the `yarn publish` step:

```
error Couldn't publish package: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@my_monorepo%2fpackage_name: Permission permission_denied: The requested installation does not exist."
```

Yet, I am able to successfully publish to Github Packages when I update the `my_monorepo/my_project/package.json` file to look like this:

```
{
  "name": "@my_org/package_name",
  "version": "0.1.30",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/my_org/my_monorepo/my_project.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
  },
  ...
}
```

i.e. the `name` has been updated from `@my_monorepo/package_name` to `@my_org/package_name`.

In this case, my package in AWS CodeArtifact is able to be installed as `@my_monorepo/package_name`, whereas my package in Github Packages is able to be installed as `@my_org/package_name`.

I'd like to use the same namespace, ideally `my_monorepo`, to install the package from whichever registry is specified.

Am I able to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

[No](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#publishing-a-package-using-a-local-npmrc-file).

Unless you owned the account with the name of the scope you're using elsewhere, and had a PAT to publish the package to that account instead of the one you're running it in.